# How to legally serve og:image

Tags: copyright

Im building a simple website where people can save links and eventually share them with others.

When a user enters an url, I fetch the meta data to present the link. 
The text, like title and description, Im just saving in a database however Im in doubt what I should do with the image.

Should I just always deeplink to the external image? Or can I save the image on my server? What are the legal options here?
I can see that facebook seems to save their own copy of images that are shared through them.

(The image will always be used in context with a link to the original link)

Comment: What is your concern? Copyright? Attribution? Ownership?

Comment: Deeplinking is nasty - the source can change it to be offensive at any moment and you probably wont notice until your users start screaming about Goatse.

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes my concern is violating copyright (or any other law). As you can tell I dont have any knowledge of this area, I just want to make sure I dont do anything "illegal" when showing these meta-data.

Comment: @Moo, yes I know, but is it OK to save a copy of the image to my own server?

Comment: Depends where you are in the world - in the US, the DMCA gives you safe harbor protections if you follow some rules - https://www.eff.org/issues/dmca

Comment: @Moo, I see. Im located in Europe. Do you have knowledge of these rules here?